# Traveling to india with toddler

Tags: visas, international-travel, india

We are both US citizens with OCI cards, our daughter is a US citizen but does not have an OCI card.

We will be traveling to India in January next year, wondering if we should get an e-visa or a normal visa? We are only going to stay for a few weeks.

Any reason not to get an e-visa?
Sounds so much simpler than a normal visa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The e-Visa is suitable for you and much easier to apply for. The normal visa allows a stay of up to 10 years but an e-Visa is issued for up to 1 year.

As you are visiting for a few weeks the e-Visa should be perfect for you and much easier to apply for.